# Field required a bean of type ... that could not be found - Error when using Springboot and Postgres

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

we are getting this error when we run our application.
We have no idea how to fix it, we have tried many solution from other SO questions but none have worked so far.

---

```
**
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
**

Description:

Field productRepository in ntnu.no.SpringDatabaseTest.service.ProductService required a bean of type 'ntnu.no.SpringDatabaseTest.repositories.ProductRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'ntnu.no.SpringDatabaseTest.repositories.ProductRepository' in your configuration.
```

---

We are using PostGres database

---

Directory structure:

```
src/
├── main/
│   └── java/
|       ├── ntnu.no.SpringDatabaseTest/
|       |   └── Bootstrap
|       |   |   └──BootStrapData
|       |   └── Controllers
|       |   |   └──ProductController
|       |   └── model
|       |   |   └──Product
|       |   └── repositories
|       |   |   └──ProductRepository
|       |   └── service
|       |   |   └──IProductService
|       |   |   └──ProductService
|       |   └── SpringDatabaseTestApplication
└── resources/
    └── application.properties
```

---

BootStrapData.java

```
package ntnu.no.SpringDatabaseTest.Bootstrap;

public class BootStrapData {
}
```

---

ProductController.java

```
package ntnu.no.SpringDatabaseTest.Controllers;

import ntnu.no.SpringDatabaseTest.model.Product;
import ntnu.no.SpringDatabaseTest.service.ProductService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class ProductController {

    private final ProductService productService;

    public ProductController(ProductService productService) {
        this.productService = productService;
    }


    @GetMapping("/showProducts")
    public String findProducts(Model model) {
        var products = (List<Product>) productService.findAll();

        model.addAttribute("products", products);

        return "showProducts";
    }

}
```

---

Product.java

```
package ntnu.no.SpringDatabaseTest.model;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="products")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long productID;
    private int price;
    private String size;
    private String productCategory;
    private String productName;
    private int productAmount;

    private String productImage;

    public Product() {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product{" +
                "productID=" + productID +
                ", price=" + price +
                ", size='" + size + '\'' +
                ", productCategory='" + productCategory + '\'' +
                ", productName='" + productName + '\'' +
                ", productAmount=" + productAmount +
                ", productImage='" + productImage + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public Long getProductID() {
        return productID;
    }

    public void setProductID(Long productID) {
        this.productID = productID;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(String size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public String getProductCategory() {
        return productCategory;
    }

    public void setProductCategory(String productCategory) {
        this.productCategory = productCategory;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public int getProductAmount() {
        return productAmount;
    }

    public void setProductAmount(int productAmount) {
        this.productAmount = productAmount;
    }

    public String getProductImage() {
        return productImage;
    }

    public void setProductImage(String productImage) {
        this.productImage = productImage;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Product product = (Product) o;

        return productID != null ? productID.equals(product.productID) : product.productID == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return productID != null ? productID.hashCode() : 0;
    }
}
```

---

Product Interface

```
package ntnu.no.SpringDatabaseTest.repositories;

import ntnu.no.SpringDatabaseTest.model.Product;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends CrudRepository<Product, Long> {
}
```

---

ProductService Interface

```
package ntnu.no.SpringDatabaseTest.service;


import ntnu.no.SpringDatabaseTest.model.Product;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public interface IProductService {

    List<Product> findAll();
}
```

---

ProductService.java

```
package ntnu.no.SpringDatabaseTest.service;


import ntnu.no.SpringDatabaseTest.repositories.ProductRepository;
import ntnu.no.SpringDatabaseTest.model.Product;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Business logic for products
 */
@Service
public class ProductService implements IProductService {

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;


    @Override
    public List<Product> findAll() {

        return (List<Product>) productRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

---

SpringDatabaseTestApplication.java

```
package ntnu.no.SpringDatabaseTest;

import ntnu.no.SpringDatabaseTest.repositories.ProductRepository;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class SpringDatabaseTestApplication{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringDatabaseTestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

---

application.properties

```
spring.main.banner-mode=off
logging.level.org.springframework=ERROR

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.sql.init.platform=postgres


spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

---

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ntnu.no</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringDatabaseTest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringDatabaseTest</name>
    <description>Test project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>





    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Is it a good idea to publish the IP with user and password of the database?

Comment: It sure aint :) @Twistleton

Comment: In controller private final ProductService productService, how are you initialising productService?

Comment: Im not sure exactly, we followed this tutorial: https://zetcode.com/springboot/postgresql/. 
If we change to autowired we get other issues. @Pirate

Comment: In the tutorial, they have @Autowired service while you dindn't. If you autowire, what error are you getting?

Comment: Same error message as before, but with this line added:
The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the part

`exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class}`

in

`SpringDatabaseTestApplication.java`

This is preventing the bean from being wired in.

Also please add dependency to postgres within your `pom.xml`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hey, if we do the following step we get a new error:
https://file.io/VuV80slm2Hrg

Comment: ok thats a different error -- do we have the postgres drivers added? 

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
  <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
</dependency>

Comment: Yea, its in the pom now

Comment: ok, i assume there is another error? whats the error?

Comment: So after removing and adding like you suggest, what we are left with now is:
https://file.io/uOwHHfjM87R0
I dont know the usual practice for sending stuff like this on SO, so hope this is ok

Comment: Pretty sure its not the correct way -- ideally you should just add the exception. In this case... "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed". few things to check. is the database running? Do we have the correct connection details in application.properties?